# warning : wint to poiter cast

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I don't know why i get a compiler warning and a segmentation fault.

Would it be possible to check it out??

```
struct thread_data{
    int  thread_id;
    char *message;
};


void *print_message_function( void *ptr )
{    
    int s,j;
    char *line;
    line = (char *) ptr;
    s=sizeof(line);
    struct thread_data td[s];

    printf("%s \n",line[2]);

    for(j=0;j+3<s;j++) {
        td[j].thread_id = (int)line[j+3];
        td[j].message = (char *)line[j+1];
        printf("message : %s \n ",td[j].message);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few bad things:

1. Why are you receiving a void* argument and casting it, why not accept char *line as an argument?
2. Why are you using `sizeof` instead of `strlen`? The `sizeof` line is just the size of a pointer (4 bytes I think).
3. This: `struct thread_data td[s]` is very bad. You can't statically allocate an array with an unknown number. Well in your case it's known since you made the mistake 2, but I'm not sure the compiler knows. Use `malloc`.
4. `line[2]` is a character, why are you using `%s` and not `%c`? - this is probably what's causing the warning/segmentation fault. It's using whatever character you have there as a pointer, and accessing illegal memory.
5. The loop will run once because of 2.

Please read a C tutorial.

Comment: @ElhamKargar - Remember to accept (the tick mark under the voting buttons on the left) an answer which has helped solve your question.